# Ratingbar: Different Color foreach star

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have to create a RatingBar designed by our graphic designer and I have no idea how that should work.
They want that each star has another color when it's filled:

[image]

Any idea how I get that? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. One way on how to do it: create 6 stars, one grey and 5 per each different color. Name the stars from star-1 to star-5. If star-4 is clicked, replace the first 4 stars(from 1 to 4) with the new star images.

Comment: Google for `android custom ratingbar`

Comment: Question should include what you tried !

Answer (score 0):

i think you can custom background of it by creating file xml in file resource. this video may be can help you more:[click here to get link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD2rCtlStT4&list=PL5uqQAwS_KDjAgLGiaCakwJV1f4vRnTLS&index=59)